# Assembly: how to add a word (2 bytes) value to a register in 4-bytes?

Tags: assembly

I want to increase a register in 2-bytes value, e.g, 0x1234.
I saw in [this link about assembly command](http://www.mathemainzel.info/files/x86asmref.html#add), that there are many options for addition.

I know that it is possible to increase a value in one byte value, with a 3-bytes command. For example, increasing ESP in 0x12:

```
 \x83\xc4\x12  # add esp,0x12
```

I don't understand the table in the link. Can someone explain it? My goal is to add a word while using 4-bytes command (without a NULL. this is for a shellcode), but I also want to understand the principals beyond the add instruction (the command alone in opcode is the full answer I'm looking for).

Comment: This looks like x86. Yes ?

Comment: So you want to add a 16-bit value to a 32-bit register? You will have to expand the 16-bit value to 32-bits to do that directly, which typically makes the encoding 6 bytes long - can be one byte shorter if the target happens to be eax. r, m, and i in that table you link to means register, memory, immediate, respectively, but download the Intel manuals to get the complete story.